# "cordova.js" can't be read or written error when copy-pasting entire project directory

Tags: javascript, cordova, osx-yosemite, corruption, finder

I'm trying to copy-paste about 8 different Cordova/Phonegap projects to a backup hard drive and they all have this same error that prevents me from successfully copying each project:

```
The Finder can't complete the operation because some data in "cordova.js" can't be read or written.(Error code -36)
```

Why do all 8 projects have this problem? I can move the cordova.js files (about 5 per project) individually but I always get the above error when I try to copy-paste the entire project.

Comment: Have you tried to `chmod 777` the file?

Comment: if you want a backup, you should pick just the root www folder, that folder doesn't include a cordova.js

Comment: I just backed up the www folder and deleted the old directories. I was wondering if this is a cordova.js specific problem, but it doesn't seem so. There are good google results that explain the -36 error in Mac OS X well (http://www.cnet.com/news/possibilities-for-overcoming-finder-error-36-in-os-x/)